# How can I detect if the Metro UI is shown?

Tags: c++, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In the Windows 8 Release Preview, you can use the Windows key to toggle between the Metro UI (does this 'dashboard' have a name?) and the view which used to be (maybe still is?) the 'desktop'.

Is there any API for testing whether the Metro UI is up programmatically - preferrably in C/C++? I looked over the [Windows API reference for Metro applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) but didn't find anything interesting.

Comment: Using [IMetroMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404160%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might give you what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Metro UI' is also called the 'Start Screen' or 'Launcher'. It can be tested for by calling [`IAppVisibility::IsLauncherVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/jj554119%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This interface is available in the Windows 8 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental question here about *why* you want this info.

Inferring from your question that you will be running this in a Metro Style app (from the fact you have looked at the guidelines), there is a better than average chance that the result will always be that you are running in the Metro interface (Since if your app is not in the foreground, it will be suspended).  The only times this might not be the case is if you are running in a background task somewhere.  Then, of course, the question is one of what you intend to do based on the results.  If you want to send a toast or tile notification it is not important what UI is currently shown - the message will get through.

If you could clarify the "why" a little more, we might be able to help with the "how".

Comment: I'm simulating user input using the `SendInput` function which requires that the application (usually a non-Metro GUI) is in front. In case the Metro GUI is up, I'll just emulate pressing the Windows key to ensure that the "old" desktop shows up again.